# How to store nlog message into sqllite? using xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin, nlog

In xamarin .ios i am using nlog ,in that if i create xls file & store message its working fine  but i tried to store into sqllite its not working .I created table called ErroLog in that 4 columns are created .database store into MyDocument folder .can you please assert me below code ,what is issue?

```
private void InitializeNLog()
{
    var saveDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

    var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    _pathToDatabase = Path.Combine(saveDir, "db_sqlite-net.db");

    // Create the database and a table to hold Person information.
    using (var conn= new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(_pathToDatabase))
    {
        conn.CreateTable<ErrorLog>();
    }

    // this coding insert is working but error value not updated
    // var errorlog = new ErrorLog { Time = "${longdate}", Level = "${level}", Lessage ="${message}", Logger = "${logger}" };
    //      
    // using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(_pathToDatabase ))
    // {
    //     db.Insert(errorlog);
    // }

    DatabaseTarget target = new DatabaseTarget();

    target.DBProvider = "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139";
    target.ConnectionString = "Data Source="+_pathToDatabase+";Version=3;";
    target.CommandText = "insert into ErrorLog( Time,Level,Lessage,Logger) values(@Time,@Level,@Lessage,@Logger)";
    // target.CommandText = "insert into ErrorLog( Time,Level,Lessage,Logger) values

    target.KeepConnection = true;

    target.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@Time","${longdate}"));
    target.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@Level","${level}"));
    target.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@Lessage","${message}"));
    target.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@Logger","${logger}"));

    SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(target, LogLevel.Info);

    _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger ();
    _logger.Info ("Sample informational message");

    // SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForTargetLogging(
    //     new FileTarget()
    //     {
    //         FileName = Path.Combine(saveDir,"${shortdate}.csv"),
    //         Layout = new CsvLayout()
    //         {
    //             Columns =
    //             {
    //                 new CsvColumn"Time", "${longdate}"),
    //                 new CsvColumn("Level", "${level}"),
    //                 new CsvColumn("Lessage", "${message}"),
    //                 new CsvColumn("Logger", "${logger}")
    //             },
    //         }
    //     },
    //     LogLevel.Info);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely overwriting your database every time you initialize.  Try this instead:

```
if (!File.Exists(_pathToDatabase)) {
  using (var conn= new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(_pathToDatabase)) {
    conn.CreateTable<ErrorLog>();
  }
}
```